# Lucene query syntax - how to add time?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch, kibana

I am new to Luncene query syntax. I am using elasticsearch/logstash and kibana for storing logfiles. But i want to filter by date and time

this works

> @timestamp:[2014-10-01  TO 2014-10-01 ]

But if I add the timesstamps like

> @timestamp:[2014-10-01 16:34:09 TO 2014-10-01 16:34:10]

this doesnot work

any help is appreociated

thanks

Comment: i didn't use kibana, but I use banana (port of kibana for solr, i have similar problem - you need to take a look into elastic search date format)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have test on my kibana/elasticsearch, this syntax works at me.

```
@timestamp:[ 2014-10-02T08:00:00 TO 2014-10-02T13:00:00]
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Wow. After two days struggling, this save my day! Thank you!